# Paint in Android Studio in background

Tags: android, canvas, android-asynctask, background, paint

Im trying to develop an App in android Studio and I want to use `Paint` and `Canvas`, basically paint something,  when I use `publishProgress`.

It would be great if any of you could tell me what is wrong with my code and why this is not painting anything.

Note. This all is in a `AsyncTaskActivity` class

```
 @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {

             publishProgress(); // Run onProgressUpdate() method
         }

    }

 @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
        // Here you can access the UI thread
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        Paint pa1= new Paint();
        pa1.setColor(Color.RED);
        pa1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        pa1.setStrokeWidth(50);

        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, pa1);
    }
```

Comment: Your canvas isn't connected to anything on the screen. You probably want to create a custom view that `onProgressUpdate` can use to display the progress.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I need to create a new class with `extends view` and try to call `ondraw()` from `onProgressUpdate()`. Is it that?

Comment: The view needs to be part of the view hierarchy or it still won't appear on the screen. So, no, you don't want to create a new view. You need to define a view in your activity's layout and then find the view. Put the actual drawing in the view's `onDraw` method as [@Vova suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41469887/535871).

Comment: ok, last question, how do I get the actual canvas which I need to pass to `onDraw` method. Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't call `onDraw` directly. Just tell the framework that the view needs to be redrawn by calling the view's `invalidate()` method. It will take care of setting up the canvas and calling `onDraw` for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not draw because you draw on new canvas instance.
For draw on screen you must create custom view and override onDraw method on it. In this method you have canvas. Try draw on it.

https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Answer (score 2):

A canvas needs to draw to either a bitmap or a view.  To draw to a Bitmap, you can create an empty Bitmap then pass it to the Canvas in the constructor.  To draw to a view, you would create a custom view and override the onDraw function which will be passed a Canvas.

Drawing to a Bitmap won't actually display to the screen unless some view draws that Bitmap to its own canvas.